# FACEBOOK_CONFIG not initialized, so WEBRick not booting

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When starting WEBRick it throws error saying my `FACEBOOK_CONFIG` is not initialized. Everything I checked looks good to me but still keep getting the same error.

Following is the error message,

```
$ rails s
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.1.4 application starting in development
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Notice: server is listening on all interfaces (--binding option)
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
c:/Sites/ThinkBlog/crumblr/config/initializers/devise.rb:235:in `block in <top (required)>': undefined method `[]' for
 nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/devise-3.3.0/lib/devise.rb:292:in `setup'
        from c:/Sites/ThinkBlog/crumblr/config/initializers/devise.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.
rb:241:in `load'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.
rb:241:in `block in load'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.
rb:232:in `load_dependency'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.
rb:241:in `load'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:648:in `block in
load_config_initializer'
```

My `FACEBOOK_CONFIG` looks like this,

```
FACEBOOK_CONFIG = YAML.load_file("#{::Rails.root}/config/facebook.yml")[::Rails.env]
```

Any idea on why `FACEBOOK_CONFIG` is not initialized?

Comment: Assuming your `FACEBOOK_CONFIG` line is 235 at your `devise.rb` initializer, then `YAML.load` is returning `nil`, so you might want to check if your path to the `facebook.yml` file is correct

Comment: @sjaime, facebook.yml is inside config folder. Path is right.

Comment: Could you post the content of your `facebook.yml`?